FullScreenCover with dynamic frame size -possible?
I have a view in which I calculate the size of an image. These size should be the size for the fullscreencover sheet.
The problem is, that the @State variable didn't change the value when I assign a new value.
I read something, and it could be that @State variable is not good for it. But what else I can do to reach my goal.
struct ExerciseDetailTopViewiPad: View {
    
    let exercise: ExerciseData
    
    @State private var showExerciseImageViewer = false
    @State private var maxWidth: CGFloat = 533
    @State private var maxHeight: CGFloat = 850
    
    var body: some View {
    
        Image(uiImage: exercise.exerciseImage.imageExerciseFromBase64)
            .onTapGesture {
                let dim: CGFloat = exercise.exerciseImage.imageExerciseFromBase64.size.height / exercise.exerciseImage.imageExerciseFromBase64.size.width
                let newWidth = maxHeight / dim - 30 // 30 height of top menu
                maxWidth = newWidth.rounded(.up) // ==> HERE IS THE PROBLEM - the assignment didn't change the variable value
                showExerciseImageViewer = true
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showExerciseImageViewer) {
                ExerciseDetailImageVieweriPad(exercise: exercise)
                    .frame(maxWidth: maxWidth, maxHeight: maxHeight)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                    .shadow(color: Color(white: 0.7), radius: 20)
                    .presentationBackground {Rectangle().fill(.clear)}
            }
    }
}


You are already using a UIImage, which lets you read the image size. So to calculate the size for the scaled image, you just need to know the size of the screen, right? The size of the screen can be found by nesting the content inside a GeometryReader.

Many posts/answers for this, use .fullscreencover(item: ...). It is designed for passing a data source for the sheet’s content. See:   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fullscreencover(item:ondismiss:content:)

"FullScreenCover with dynamic frame size" is an oxymoron a full screen cover covers the entire screen. look at sheet and detents

In my code I use the UIImage to get the dimension and the calculate the new width in the OnTabGesture function. I use the fullscreencover function with a frame which should have the new width. The problem is, that my @State variable maxWidth can not be changed and is always 533. What can I do?

As I mentioned in my comment, use .fullscreencover(item: ...). It is designed for passing a data source for the sheet’s content.
Alternatively, you can capture the variables (maxWidth, maxHeight) when you call
fullScreenCover, as shown in the example code.
This will present a fullScreenCover
and inside it will display your ExerciseDetailImageVieweriPad view
with the updated .frame(maxWidth: maxWidth, maxHeight: maxHeight)
 .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showExerciseImageViewer) { [maxWidth, maxHeight] in
     ExerciseDetailImageVieweriPad(exercise: exercise)
         .frame(maxWidth: maxWidth, maxHeight: maxHeight)
         .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
         .shadow(color: Color(white: 0.7), radius: 20)
         .presentationBackground {Rectangle().fill(.clear)}
 }

If your question is about resizing the fullScreenCover itself,
then just use .sheet with .presentationDetents([.height(maxHeight)]), such as:
.sheet(isPresented: $showExerciseImageViewer) { [maxWidth, maxHeight] in
            ExerciseDetailImageVieweriPad(exercise: exercise)
                .frame(maxWidth: maxWidth, maxHeight: maxHeight)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .shadow(color: Color(white: 0.7), radius: 20)
                .presentationBackground {Rectangle().fill(.clear)}
                .presentationDetents([.height(maxHeight)])
}


Great, the fullScreenCover definition with [maxWidth, maxHeight] is the solution. Many thanks.
